# Show Records from parent table that have child records less than 4

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display records from my sql from the parent table that have child records less than 4 (having no child records at all is also fine), Need SQL query please.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
  pt.id, pt.somefield, COUNT(pt.id) as c
FROM
  parenttable pt
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  chiledtable ct
ON
  ct.parenttable_id = pt.id
GROUP BY
  pt.id
HAVING
  c <= 4
```

Comment: I think this would report childless rows as having one child

Comment: The HAVING condition should probably be `c < 4`.

Comment: @Andomar it is intentional as it is requested "having no records at all is also fine" we include those rows

Comment: @AndriyM OK, if it strictly less than 4, we must have < 4 and not <= 4, but it must be obvious

Comment: Andomar meant that, even though your query does include childless parents in the output, it will report them as having 1 child instead of 0. I think you should change `COUNT(pt.id)` to something like `COUNT(c.id)` (basically, any column from `c` would do).

Comment: OK, agree, yet it depends if this field will be used at all

Comment: Well, yes it's true that the OP didn't ask for the count column. But if you do put it there, why make it return values that might cause confusion?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to calculate the number of child rows:

```
select  *
from    ParentTable as p
left join
        (
        select  parentid
        ,       count(*) as cnt
        from    ChildTable
        group by
                parentid
        ) as c
on      c.parentid = p.id
where   c.cnt <= 3
```

Comment: Despite your using LEFT JOIN, this will omit childless parents. (I don't know if that was your intention, although if it was, why LEFT JOIN?) And, since the OP said, "less than 4", the condition should probably be `c.cnt between 1 and 3`.

Comment: @AndriyM: Omitting childless parents is intentional, per question "having no records at all is also fine".  You're right about "less than 4", edited.  The left join makes it easier to filter for childless parents; you'd only have to edit the where clause

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear with regard to childless parents. I meant that your query will *not* return them. It's because the WHERE clause will filter them out. Just consider: a `ParentTable` row has no matches in `ChildTable` (i.e. it's a childless parent). For that parent, the `c` derived table will return NULLs, right? But your WHERE condition, `c.cnt between ...` will evaluate to `unknown` (because it's effectively `NULL between ...`). So the childless parent will not be output.

Comment: Here's a [quick illustration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edab5/1) of what I mean. Three parents: one has no children, one over 4 children, and one under 4. Your query returns only one parent.

Comment: @AndriyM: Hehe, I interpreted "is also fine" as "i am not interested in them".  So I didn't return them.  I guess the question can be read in two ways.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misunderstood your interpretation, sorry. :)

Comment: It's showing only records that have child records between 1 and 4, I mentioned that having no records (edited no child records) is also fine, edit please...

Comment: Nice job! Only it's still not returning childless parents. (Please ask yourself if you really expect rows with `cnt=0` from the subquery.) :)